# Subsequent Pages on Create-React-App Not Found on Reload

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I created an app with [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and when I push it to my server, it works as expected until I try to reload any page other than the main index.html page, e.g., mywebpage.com/about.

I imagine that this is an issue about the lack of any static about.html file, but I'm not sure how to remedy this.

How do I adjust the app to look back to index.js and to dynamically create the about.html page?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive if I'm mistaken, but can't you create a method that creates the html page on refresh? I don't think that would cause any problems.